# How to use GridBagLayout to make a JLabel 1 column wide and then a JTextField 2 columns wide (for a total width 3 columns)

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I've read the documentation for `GridBagLayout` and I can't make sense of it. I basically want to accomplish something like this:

[image]

I made some example code to help me figure this out. How can I modify this code to accomplish this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JLabel label = new JLabel("label");
        JTextField field = new JTextField();

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("label2");
        JTextField field2 = new JTextField();

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        //gbc.weightx = ??
        jp.add(label, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        //gbc.weightx = ??
        jp.add(field, gbc);

        JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
        jp2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc2.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc2.gridx = 0;
        gbc2.gridy = 0;
        gbc2.gridwidth = 1;
        //gbc2.weightx = ??
        jp2.add(label2, gbc2);
        gbc2.gridx = 1;
        gbc2.gridwidth = 2;
        //gbc2.weightx = ??
        jp2.add(field2, gbc2);

        JPanel jpContainer = new JPanel();
        jpContainer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jpContainer, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        jpContainer.add(jp);
        jpContainer.add(jp2);

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(300, 100);
        f.setContentPane(jpContainer);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

---

EDIT: Changed JTextArea to JTextField

Comment: You can't guarantee a 1/3 - 2/3 split of the space. You used the GridBagConstraints.BOTH fill on the JLabel and the JTextField, so both fields will expand horizontally to fill the space. Try the GridBagConstraints.NONE fill on the JLabel and see if that looks better. –

Comment: @Gilbert Thanks, I'll try that.  My main concern isn't getting a perfect 1/3 - 2/3 split, I'm more concerned with making sure the `JTextField` components that are stacked on top of each other line up. I suspect I'll end up having to use a different layout manager. I originally used `GridLayout` but giving the `JLabel` and the `JTextField` an equal amount of space looked silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GridBagLayout columnWidths you can manually adjust the widths and then set the GridBagConstraints fill to `GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL` :

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Insets;


public class Example extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Example frame = new Example();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Example() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[] {100, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("jlabel");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNewLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblNewLabel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel, gbc_lblNewLabel);

        textField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_textField.gridx = 1;
        gbc_textField.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(textField, gbc_textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("jlabel2");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNewLabel_1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc_lblNewLabel_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_lblNewLabel_1.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lblNewLabel_1.gridy = 1;
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1, gbc_lblNewLabel_1);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textField_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textField_1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_textField_1.gridx = 1;
        gbc_textField_1.gridy = 1;
        contentPane.add(textField_1, gbc_textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
    }

}
```

Of course, if you want to maintain the 1/3 Label and 2/3 JTextField, you might consider using a MigLayout as such:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MigLayoutExample extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MigLayoutExample frame = new MigLayoutExample();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public MigLayoutExample() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow 33][grow 66]", "[][]"));

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel, "cell 0 0");

        textField = new JTextField();
        contentPane.add(textField, "cell 1 0,growx");
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("New label");
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1, "cell 0 1");

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        contentPane.add(textField_1, "cell 1 1,growx");
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have two components on each row so you can only have two columns.

If you want the JTextArea to occupy more space then define the JTextArea like:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(3, 30);
```

to control the size of the text area by specifying the row/columns of the text area.

I'm not sure why you are using a JTextArea. It seems like a JTextField would be more appropriate. You can also specify the columns when you create a JTextField. Check out the JTextField API.

Comment: Thanks for your help @camickr. I actually meant to use `JTextField` so I modified my question and changed all the `JTextArea`s to `JTextField`s. I made this code quickly to illustrate the problem I'm having. I see what you are saying about only having two components so I can't have three columns, but I'm still struggling to understand how I can make the `JLabel` take up 1/3 of the space and the `JTextField` take up the remaining 2/3.